# My styles get overridden by the html I get with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am building a mass mailer system where you can see a preview of the email before it is sent. I render the email html into a preview box using jquery -- `$().html(theHtml).`

Html emails use all inline css for their styles. When I fill the html, it overrides some of my css.

I am looking for a solution to completely stop this from happening. Is there any way to self contain the email html/css so it does not affect the entire document?

I understand that adding !important to my styles will do the trick, but it is not a very scalable option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `!important` is fine for overriding inline styles IMO.

Comment: What about just using an iframe?

Comment: inline styles such as `style="foo:bar"`? or embedded such as `<style></style>`. If it's `<style></style>`, you just need to make your style selectors more specific than theirs. Specificity goes `Inline > ID > Class/Attribute/psudo > tagname/psudoelements`. If it's `style="foo:bar"`, it shouldn't be affecting the rest of your document.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately !important is the only way to override an inline style - that's just how specificity works.

However you might be able to get around it by making all of the "wrapper" CSS (e.g. the CSS for YOUR page, not the HTML email preview) more specific by using IDs and classes etc so that their styles don't get overridden by generic style declarations embedded in the HTML email.

I'm a little confused though - are you trying to override "inline" styles (as in elements with the style="your css here" attribute) or embedded CSS (e.g. "your css here")?  If it's the latter, just make important stuff more specific in your own CSS.

Some more info about specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Using an iframe as Sander suggested might be a simpler solution than trying to restructure your CSS specificity rules though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same `class`/`id` names for your website and the emails? This should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a [pseudo-namespace](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070321/css-practice-pseudo-namespaces-in-complex-projects/) for your CSS.

Basically, add an arbitrary prefix to your CSS that won't be contained in the inlined 3rd-party content: `<div class='foo'>` becomes `<div class='myapp-foo'>`

Having used this practice on our projects recently, it requires only a bit more discipline, but makes the app easier to manage for embedding other content.